# Data Binding a Nested ListView to an ObservableCollection using Linq-to-SQL in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, linq-to-sql

There is a high quantity of code behind my specific question, so I will try to understand the methodology behind what I am trying to achieve, instead of providing/requesting any coding examples. Having said that, I will post and accept as much code hereafter as it takes to achieve this level of understanding - we'll see how this goes!

**The Context:**

I have developed a Nested ListView. That is a ListView that contains another ListView in each ListViewItem (a little List-View-Ception, if you like).

The Upper Listview needs to contain data from one table, and the Nested Listview needs to contain data from the related table (linked with foreign keys)

Originally, I developed a class that defined a Nested ObservableCollection (There is more data in the class/listview than it's nested collection - but we'l ignore this for now!).

I then:

- populated the ObservableCollection using my SQL Database class with an attractive-looking loop
- populated each nested collection with another attractive-looking loop; manually selecting the correct data from the related table
- set the DataContext of my Listview to the Collection
- and finally set the binding values in XAML to equal the public names of my observable collection's class

Problem Solved. Question Answered. Thank you very much.

I then:

- Discovered Linq-To-SQL
- Deleted my SQL Database Class
- Deleted my ObservableCollection Class
- Continued a deletion-rampage that will be remembered by my program's variables for years to come.

So, I created Linq-to-SQL classes, connected to my Database and dragged the tables into the interface provided.

I was astounded when I witnessed the contents of the designer.cs - a perfectly modelled structure that represented my two tables so perfectly I had to pause in awe.

I then:

- Created a new class that inherits an ObservableCollection (of the table in my database)
- Put a foreach loop in my new class' constructor to populate the collection
- Created my first object of this class, sending a Linq-to-Sql classes' data context object (AKA: creating a collection of the data in my table)
- Re-named my Binding Path values to match that of the columns in my database
- Obliterated the F5 key on my keyboard

The Listview contained data - and it has to be said, I was impressed by this system.

**The Problem:**

However, the Nested Listview for each item was empty!

So, I then:

- Checked the database; the second table contained data, linked correctly with foreign keys
- Noticed in the designer.cs that the nested data would be stored in an EntitySet
- Debugged and Checked the ObservableCollection

I found the data and was impressed that the Linq-To-SQL classes had separated the second tables data correctly to each collection item based on the foreign key values. In fact I was very impressed.

However, I don't know how to bind these values and get them to display! They are here (in debug):

```
- TheDataContextObject[N-Item]->TheNestedEntitySet->non-public members->entities->[The List of Nested Data for that Item]
```

**The data in that entityset is correct - I just don't understand how I can bind to these values.**

All help is appreciated - I will try and improve the general quality of the question as time passes and will be open to all suggestions.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Discover Entity Framework, please ^-^. Oh, and MVVM.

Comment: @StefanDenchev - with pleasure. Would you be able to provide me with a recommended link that I am not likely to find in the google search I am imminently going to make... Thanks.

Comment: Sure, [here](http://reedcopsey.com/series/windows-forms-to-mvvm/)'s MVVM and you can check [Julie Lerman](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/)'s tutorials at pluralsight..

Answer (score 0):

Your Entity class will have your 'foreign key' classes as Navigation properties. You can access these properties like any other C# property. For example, a `Person` class/object may have a relationship with a `ClubsAndSocieties` class/object which is another `EntitySet`. C# wise you'd access it like this:

```
Person.ClubsAndSocieties
```

You can then bind to this property in the usual way.

Inspecting it though you may find it is just null, if your original query to bring it back was like this:

```
var myPeople = ObjectContext.People;
```

This is the default loading. If you want to bring back specific navigation properties of an Entity then you'll need to bring back your entity like this:

```
var myPeople = ObjectContext.People.Include("ClubsAndSocieties");
```

or

```
var myPeople = ObjectContext.People.Include(()=>ClubsAndSocieties);
```

depending on your EF version.

You can keep chaining these includes to bring back all the navigation properties you are interested in. So if a Person also has a link to FamilyMembers then your query to bring back the whole graph would look like this:

```
var myPeople = ObjectContext.People.Include("ClubsAndSocieties").Include("FamilyMembers";
```

As Stefan said, you would do well to discover Entity Framework (linq to sql is a start in the right direction) and MVVM.